# Android Gallery objects obtained from network to Individual gallery object

Tags: android

GridGalleryThumbnailFragment to photoActivity

All the gallery objects are obtained from internet, my current setup is whenever user reaches the Fragment a network request is made and if it successful the gallery objects with thumbnails and image urls are returned. When the user clicks on an individual item a intent will start the activity and puts extra intent data with image title and image url and the image is opened in full screen. Now I want to implement a next/previous functionality in the Activity, what is the best approach for it.

1. Make a second network request in the activity and get the values from this new adapter.
2. Remove the activity workflow and just replace View in the fragment with the full image view.
3. Store all the values obtained the first time around in android local storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two adapters which have the same data in the same order:
a GalleryAdapter and a ImagePagerAdapter

When the GalleryView starts the ImageView the ImageView needs the gallery-s current offset. next/previous is just adding 1 to or subtracting 1 from the offset.

I have implemented something similar but based on a database query using a CursorAdapter and a android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter . Both GalleryView and ImageView share the same sql.

[Update]

If you donot want to load the data twice you can use a [LoaderManager](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) where GalleryView and ImageView both use the same loader-Impementation/loader-ID

Comment: Yeah so I was gonna create a second adapter for image, but that would also mean I need to query the network two times once in fragment and again in activity.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much, I guess I have lot more to learn in android.

Comment: Although your answer is correct and I accepted it, I think I will go with 3rd option as it seems to be the best option in the long run as the android device doesnt have to waste lot of memory.